# Bind9 socket.c unexpected error

Tags: debian, bind

The `named` process is giving this kind of error the whole day:

```
Jun 17 12:50:43 s named[24479]: socket.c:5274: unexpected error:
Jun 17 12:50:43 s named[24479]: connect(198.41.0.4#53) 22/Invalid argument
```

What is this error?

`Named` (BIND 9.8.4-rpz2+rl005.12-P1) runs on Debian GNU/Linux squeeze/sid x32. From machine I can telnet to this address (a.root-servers.net.), also I can resolve IP address to name with nslookup

Comment: Hi welcome to slashdot. Add Linux version/software versions to this post and any future posts please. It seems BIND was unable to connect to that IP. Could be a transient error. Is it your BIND configured for IPv6 only or is the IPv4 interface down? Have you allowed besides UDP/53, TCP/53, if using firewall rules? Test 198.41.0.4 with a dig/nslookup from the BIND machine

Comment: Have you restarted named?

Comment: Several times, same problem

Comment: what does `sudo tcpdump -nvvv host 198.41.0.4` says? leave it running until you have a couple of answers.

Comment: Tcpdump captures: http://pastebin.com/77cLNBk4

Comment: seems more or less normal...what is the interval of time the error appears? You also seem to have 53/UDP and TCP open to the outside, so it is not port blocking.

Comment: Something about one week

Comment: every 5 minutes, every hour...how is it?

Comment: Ou.. many entrys for few seconds and repeats every 30s

Comment: What are your RPZ configs?

Comment: The error seems a bit odd...have you changed DNSsec or RPZ configs lately?

Answer (score 0):

I would bet on a transient error, however if the command tools work, and you have this error something is amiss. Maybe a BIND bug, maybe some firewall configuration (inspectors)

Your OS and BIND are quite old and EOL (2013 since it is the testing branch).

I would upgrade both urgently; if you have not kernels and BIND compiled by hand, they have already a couple nasty bugs that can be explored remotely.

If the issue continues to be present, then I would debug further on the problem.

Comment: Thank you. I will upgrade distribution and bind ant let you know

Comment: This weekend I have upgraded system from Debian 6 to Debian 7. Bind installed version 1:9.8.4.dfsg.P1-6+nm, but still getting same error.

Comment: Interesting. While we did not deleted the hints about your servers, it seemed to me I could connect to your powerdns server, but not your BIND server from the outside. A chance is also increasing the debug level of BIND, or increasing monitoring in some other way. Do you have firewalls in the way to outside, PIXes or ASAs? Why not Debian 8? I am running it here.

Comment: Yes, I have two DNS servers, one BIND ant second PowerDNS.
ip route get shows that to that IP address I go over public IP address, so no firewall is in the way

Comment: Having a route of public IP addresses is no guarantee there are no firewalls, however I do trust you know better about your setup. I am a little busy right now, will came back later with ideas for debugging.

Comment: I had noticed it earlier. You managed basically to install the same version of BIND, and a Debian version which already has not so frequent upgrades.

Comment: Sorry for long response. I will try to upgrade distribution and bind to newest version